# Django Postgresql Configuration ERROR : ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

A newbie to Django!!

In the process of switching from sqlite3 to postgresql,
I tried to follow the steps in the link.

> http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/install-and-configure-posgresql-for-django

settings.py (added Database settings as follows)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_env_variable('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

> In Django shell

```
>>>from trydjango import settings
>>>settings.DATABASES
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': '', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE':    None, 
'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 
'TEST': {'COLLATION': None, 'CHARSET': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}, 
'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
```

> ERROR :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. 
Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation 
for more details.
```

Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: You're getting the name/user/password from environment variables. But have you actually set those environment variables anywhere?

Comment: Yes !! I have set.

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in settings.DATABASES configurations

settings.py (The database settings now)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'myproject',
         'USER': 'myprojectuser',
         'PASSWORD': 'password',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

and there were some mistakes in database configuration with $DATABASE_URL
which have been corrected as

```
#Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

then applying migrations using

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

solved the issue.

Now the DATABASE configuration in Django shell

```
>>> from trydjango.settings import DATABASES
>>> DATABASES
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'myproject', 
'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'HOST': 'localhost', 
'USER': 'myprojectuser', 'TEST': {'COLLATION': None, 'CHARSET': None, 
'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}, 'PASSWORD': 'password', 'PORT': ''}}
```

Done

Answer (score 0):

Answering instead of commenting due to rep.

Your settings.py shows this: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
But your shell output shows: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'

Are you sure you have everything configured correctly?

Comment: That was due to improper configuration of the settings.DATABASES